# Is the func.prototype.constructor exactly same as func?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function A(name){
    this.name=name;
}
```

`If A===A.prototype.constructor` then invoking both of them does not set the name variable on window object

Only `A("abhishek")` sets the variable on window and `A.prototype.constructor("randommm")` does not!

Can someone please explain what's the difference, I am thinking that

```
A.prototype.constructor("randommm")
```

is called from a different context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they run in different contexts.

You're creating a hoisted function in the local scope, which means its default context, unless you bind it to something else, will be `window` (or at any rate the global namespace) when you invoke it.

Calling it via `prototype.constructor`, though, calls it as a method of the `prototype` object, so it's logical that the prototype is the context.

```
function A() { alert(this); }
A(); //context = window
A.prototype.constructor(); //context = prototype
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgy47skc/).

Comment: `this` != context. And what `this` is in the function has nothing to do with the scope (global or otherwise) in which you define it except for arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
A()
```

calls the function with `this` being `window`

```
A.prototype.constructor("randommm")
```

calls the constructor property of `A.prototype` which is its context.

However i don't see the sense of calling a constructor without `new` ...

Comment: *"calls the function with this being window"* Only in loose mode. In strict mode, it's `undefined`. And more accurately, in loose mode it calls it with `this` set to a reference to the global object; on browsers, `window` is a global variable that also references the global object.

Answer (score 1):

`A.prototype.constructor("randommm")` is setting the property `name` on `A.prototype`:

```js
function A(name){
    this.name=name;
}

A.prototype.constructor("John Doe");

console.log(A.prototype.name); // John Doe
```

The value of `this` will be whatever before the `.` in the call to the function (unless, ofcourse, it is explicitly specified using `bind`).

Answer (score 0):

as a side note if you really want to use the constructor instead of function this

```
A.prototype.constructor.bind(this)("randommm")
```

works. But I think it doesn't make any sense in this case

Answer (score 0):

The function being called is the same in both cases, what changes is the context in which it is being called.

Here the function is called on its own, so it uses global context:

```
A("abhishek")
```

Here the function is called on A.prototype, so it uses A.prototype context:

```
A.prototype.constructor("randommm")
```